# Как визуализировать точки которые расставил для себя алгоритм kNN?

Tags: python, pandas, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn, визуализация

Задавал вопрос как визуализировать точки которые расставил для себя алгоритм kNN?

То есть, у меня есть DataFrame 3000 объектов с 18 признаками, классифицирую данные с помощью алгоритма kNN. Науч.рук. ставит задачу визуализировать результат работы kNN алгоритма и точки разукрасить в 2 цвета.

Мне подсказали что для визуализации n-мерного пространства нужно уменьшить размерность, порылся нашел в sklearn.decomposition. KernelPCA для уменьшения размерности, но работа kernelPca != kNN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При помощи классификатора (`kNN` в вашем случае), вы получаете метки классов для каждого экземпляра из набора данных. Для визуализации полученные метки можно использовать в качестве цвета точек. Дальше нам остается уменьшить размерность исходного датасета до 2х или 3х измерений и отобразить это на графике.

Пример с [ирисами Фишера (Андерсона)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8B_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0):

````
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE

import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# data
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = pd.DataFrame(iris.data, columns=iris["feature_names"])
y = iris.target

# dimensionality reduction
n = 2
X_embedded = TSNE(n_components=n, perplexity=25).fit_transform(X)

#visualization
res = pd.DataFrame(X_embedded, columns=np.arange(1, n+1)).add_prefix("feat_")
res["name"] = iris["target_names"][y]
res["size"] = 10
res["hover_data"] = [
    f"""sepal length: {x["sepal length (cm)"]}
sepal width: {x["sepal width (cm)"]}
petal length: {x["petal length (cm)"]}
petal width: {x["petal width (cm)"]}"""
    for i,x in X.iterrows()
]
fig = px.scatter(
    res, x="feat_1", y="feat_2", color="name", size="size",
    hover_name="hover_data")
fig.write_html("/tmp/tSNE.html")```
````

PS в качестве библиотеки визуализации я выбрал [Plotly](https://plotly.com/python/plotly-fundamentals/), т.к. эта библиотека предоставляет очень богатые возможности для интерактивной визуализации данных в Python.

[результат](https://safenote.co/r/602df41641b900@54060462)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо то что надо, ток с Plotly не разобрался отрисовал в plt. спасибо еще раз.

Answer (score 3):

Напишу тоже вариант ответа, вдруг так будет понятнее.

Тренировочные данные:

- `X` - исходные данные, 18 фич (и не важно сколько сэмплов)
- `y` - целевая переменная, может принимать 2 значения (2 цвета)

Тестовые данные:

- `X'` - дано
- `y'` - нужно предсказать

`kNN`:

- обучается на примере `X -> y`
- предсказывает из `X' -> y'`

`PCA` (хотя для отображения лучше взять `tSNE`):

- обучается на объединении `X` и `X'`
- делает из `X` (18 фич) `->` некое `X2` (2 фичи)
- делает из `X'` (18 фич) `->` `X2'` (2 фичи)

Вам остаётся только нарисовать:

- взять 2 фичи из `X2` как координаты, а цвета из `y`
- взять 2 фичи из `X2`' как координаты, а цвета из `y'`

Причём, для предсказанных цветов лучше взять цвета другой яркости/насыщенности, чтобы они были похожи на цвета из обучения, но несколько всё же отличались.

Comment: Да все так и сделал:) Только обучал на одном x' и пересказывал по ней y'. Получается будет правильней научить на x + x'?

Comment: @Захар Это только про снижение размерности через PCA например, не перепутайте с основным предсказанием  :)  Да, PCA правильнее на объединении учить, иначе может немного съехать всё

Answer (score 2):

Все правильно. KernelPCA -  это алгоритм специального рода кластеризации, kNN -  это алгоритм классификации. Они и не могут быть тождественными.

Скорее всего вы недопонимаете задачу, вернее того, что от вас хочет ваш руководитель. И наверное в слово "визуализация" он вкладывает некий смысл, который вы почему-то не улавливаете. Может он всего-лишь хочет чтобы вы ему нарисовали 18*18 диаграмм разброса (нормальная так задачка для первокурсника, только начинающего изучать Python). А может хочет, что-бы вы написали приложение, в котором пользователь выбирал например три признака и получал отображение своего 18-мерного пространства в указанное трехмерное (Это уже курсовой для 3-4 курса). Или отбирал десяток объектов и строил радарную диаграмму с 18 лучами. Вот подойдите и спросите его, как конкретно он хочет визуализировать.

Потому как "разукрасить точки в 2 цвета" - это не kNN. Точнее говоря, это всего лишь исходный набор данных, на котором алгоритм может работать. Но вот работать алгоритм все равно будет не с цветами, а с метками класса.

Comment: Что-то ответ недописанный...