# Как сделать интерактивный scatter, чтобы при наведении на точку высвечивалось значение одного из столбцов?

Tags: python, pandas, анализ-данных, визуализация, plotly

У меня есть [такой датасет](https://www.kaggle.com/hwassner/TwitterFriends):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу сделать *scatter*, чтобы по `y` был `friendsCount`, а по `x` - `followersCount`, а при наведении на точку показывался `screenName`.

Пока у меня получилось так:

```
data = {
"screenName": ["LlngoMakeEmCum_", "_notmichelle", "jesseayye", "MrBrianLloyd", "sarahdorat_16", "wanderIustregui", "andhesonit", "Jas_Thxku", "KLitzau", "ThePettyHomo"], 
"followersCount": [319, 275, 120, 492, 128, 479, 1875, 582, 688, 204], 
"friendsCount": [112, 115, 107, 325, 218, 131, 111, 281, 186, 226]
}

twitterData = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
twitterData[["screenName", "followersCount", "friendsCount"]].plot.scatter(x="followersCount", y="friendsCount", backend="plotly")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так, чтобы дополнительно высвечивался `screenName`?

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте [так](https://plotly.com/python/line-and-scatter/#set-size-and-color-with-column-names):

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.scatter(df, x="followersCount", y="friendsCount", hover_data=["screenName"])
fig.show()
```

PS [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1245462/211923) можно посмотреть чуть более сложный вариант использования.

Comment: Спасибо, то, что надо!